# Is there any way to show a notifee notification when app is in killed state

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

So, I am using react native with expo. And I use expo notifications to send and receive push notifications along with fcm which is handled by expo itself. Now, since the expo-notifications library doesnt allow much customizations, i want to use notifee library to show the notifications. Now this works fine when the app is open or running in background, but I want to know is there any way to show the notifee notification instead of the expo-notifications when the app is in killed state. I could probably use FCM with notifee but transitioning to that is bit time consuming at this stage for me. Would be great if someone has any solution.